# How can I transform a .properties file during a Gradle build?

Tags: gradle

As part of a deploy task in Gradle, I want to change the value of a property in `foo.properties` to point to a production database instead of a development database.

I'd rather not replace the whole file outright, as it's rather large and it means we would have to maintain two separate versions that only differ on a single line.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the ant.propertyfile task:

```
    ant.propertyfile(
        file: "myfile.properties") {
        entry( key: "propertyName", value: "propertyValue")
        entry( key: "anotherProperty", operation: "del")
    }
```

Comment: How can we have change property across multiple files using wild card or folder ?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to fire off an ant "replace" task that does what you want: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

```
ant.replace(file: "blah", token: "wibble", value: "flibble")
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a properties object, then create the file object with the targeted properties file path, load the file on the properties object with load, set the desired property with setProperty, and save the changes with store.

```
def var = new Properties() 
File myfile = file("foo.properties");

var.load(myfile.newDataInputStream())
var.setProperty("db", "prod")
var.store(myfile.newWriter(), null)
```

Comment: Please add some documentation/explanation.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to code a task that uses `java.util.Properties` to write the file. If you really want to incrementally update the file, you'll have to implement this on your own. Or maybe you find an Ant task that does what you want (all Ant tasks can be used as-is from Gradle). For best results, you should also declare the inputs and outputs of the task, so that Gradle only executes the tasks when the properties file needs to be changed.

Comment: You can also use Apache commons configurations library which provides a more convenient API (http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html). Of course, you'll still have to implement most of the logic yourself.

Comment: Ant's [PropertyFile task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ReplaceTokens`

Say you have a file called `db.properties` in `src/main/java/resources/com.stackoverlow` (the location doesn't matter) with the following content

```
database.url=@url@
```

Note that the `@` surrounding the `url` text is required.

You can then define this in your `build.gradle` file.

```
processResources {
        filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                "url": "https://stackoverflow.com"
        ]
}
```

When you build your code, this would replace `@url@` with `https://stackoverflow.com`.

If you are only interested in applying this rule to a specific file, you can add a `filesMatching`

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('**/db.properties') {
        filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                "url": "https://stackoverflow.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

See [gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files) for more explanation