# Gradle: save property file

Tags: android, gradle, properties-file

I use NewRelic in my project. It needs newrelic.properties file with application token. I need to create several builds with different token. In gradle for genereting properties I use next snippet:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("com.newrelic.application_token","MYTOKEN")
```

How can I save it to my app folder? I need "newrelic.properties" file with text "com.newrelic.application_token=MYTOKEN" in root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use more simple way:

```
ant.propertyfile(file: "newrelic.properties") {
            entry( key: "com.newrelic.application_token", value: "AA165ad2e3e518***********************sd2")
        }
```

from this:
[How can I transform a .properties file during a Gradle build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035356/how-can-i-transform-a-properties-file-during-a-gradle-build)

Answer (score 2):

You can use -P flag to indicate build profile:

```
gradle clean build -Pprofile=dev
```

Then use it in build script:

```
File propsFile = new File('/libs/newrelic.properties')
if (project.getProperty('profile') == "dev") {
    println "Target environment: $profile"
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.setProperty("com.newrelic.application_token","DEV_TOKEN")
    props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), null)
}
```