# How to update a values in properties file during gradle jar build process?

Tags: java, gradle

I have `build.gradle` file:

```
...
jar {
   baseName 'dev-filename'
   manifest {
      attributes (
         'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.collect {it.getName() }.join(' ')
         'Main-Class': 'package.of.main.class'
      )
   }
}
...
```

And properties file `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
...
database.username=dev_user
database.password=dev_password
...
```

How to create tasks (dev and prod) to build jar file and update values in the property file?

**UPD1:**
I've tried next, but it doesn't work:

```
...
jar {
   baseName 'dev-filename'
   manifest {
      attributes (
         'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.collect {it.getName() }.join(' ')
         'Main-Class': 'package.of.main.class'
      )
   }
   ant.propertyfile(file: 'application.properties') {
      entry(key: 'database.username', value: 'new_username')
      entry(key: 'database.password', value: 'new_password')
   }
}
...
```

Comment: You want to update the properties file that is already inside ? is it not better to modify it before it gets packed? and btw creating a fat jar like this is not a preferable solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I transform a .properties file during a Gradle build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035356/how-can-i-transform-a-properties-file-during-a-gradle-build)

Comment: I've tried this example. It doesn't make any effect for me

Comment: then show how did you tried it and provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: I provided example of my try

Comment: you want a separate task to update the properties.

Comment: Firstly I want to find the solution how to replace the value in the properties file.

Comment: ideally, you should extend `processResources` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to process your resources before packing it.

```
processResources {
  filesMatching('*.properties') {
    filter( ReplaceTokens, tokens:['foo' : 'bar'])
  }
}
```

Comment: This script creates a new `application.properties` file in the root folder of the project

Comment: @Hugh hmm weird

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like:

```
task jarProd(type: Jar) {
    doFirst {
        ant.property(file: "build/resource/main/config/application.properties") {
            entry(key: "database.username", value: "prod_user",
            entry(key: "database.password", value: "prod_password"
        }
    }
    baseName 'myapp'
    manifest {
      attributes (
         'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.collect {it.getName() }.join(' ')
         'Main-Class': 'package.of.main.class'
      )
   }
   with jar
}

task zipProd(dependsOn: jarProd, type: Zip) {
    baseName 'prod/myapp'
    from ('build/libs') {
        include("myapp.jar")
    }
    from configurations.runtime
}

task jarTest(type: Jar) {
    doFirst {
        ant.property(file: "build/resource/main/config/application.properties") {
            entry(key: "database.username", value: "test_user",
            entry(key: "database.password", value: "test_password"
        }
    }
    baseName 'myapp'
    manifest {
      attributes (
         'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.collect {it.getName() }.join(' ')
         'Main-Class': 'package.of.main.class'
      )
   }
   with jar
}

task zipTest(dependsOn: jarTest, type: Zip) {
    baseName 'test/myapp'
    from ('build/libs') {
        include("myapp.jar")
    }
    from configurations.runtime
}

task zip {
    dependsOn zipTest
    dependsOn zipProd
}
```

As a result, I have 2 same zip files with different credentials for DB