# Set active spring profile with bootWar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, war, spring-profiles, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to set the active spring profile when building a WAR file. I'm building the WAR file with `gradle bootWar`

I managed to find a solution that works for `gradle bootRun -Pprofiles=prod`

```
bootRun {
  if (project.hasProperty('profiles')) {
    environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: profiles
  }
}
```

But

```
bootWar {
  if (project.hasProperty('profiles')) {
    environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: profiles
  }
}
```

Gives me this error

> Could not find method environment() for arguments [{SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=staging}] on task ':bootWar' of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootWar.

How do I make it work for WAR files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Links refer to a demo project in which I do the same you are trying to do right now, but with some extra complexity, read first the property, etc. and set different profiles as active: `development`, `testing`, `production` and some other SO posts)*

---

Suppose we want to set the active profile as `production`.

In the `build.gradle` you could create a [task](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/80c6c17759a9a076fdf0d5597d52b485da747fb7/server/build.gradle#L163) which writes the property [`spring.profiles.active`](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/80c6c17759a9a076fdf0d5597d52b485da747fb7/server/src/main/resources/application.properties#L102) using the [`ant.propertyfile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035356/how-can-i-transform-a-properties-file-during-a-gradle-build/20549712#20549712) like this:

```
task setProductionConfig() {
    group = "other"
    description = "Sets the environment for production mode"
    doFirst {
        /*
           notice the file location ("./build/resources/main/application.properties"),
           it refers to the file processed and already in the build folder, ready
           to be packed, if you use a different folder from `build`, put yours
           here
        */
        ant.propertyfile(file: "./build/resources/main/application.properties") {
            entry(key: "spring.profiles.active", value: "production")
        }
    }
    doLast {
        // maybe put some notifications in console here
    }
}
```

Then you tell the `bootWar` task it depends on this previous task we made like [this](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/80c6c17759a9a076fdf0d5597d52b485da747fb7/server/build.gradle#L254):

```
bootWar {
    dependsOn setProductionConfig
}
```

Comment: Any change you got a solution when using .yml files?

Comment: Never tried using yml files. That'd be interesting, though.